# Looping a formula over a field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I have some data in Excel like this:

```
| id | categorie |  number |
| 1  |     a     |  123    |
| 2  |     b     |  23     |
| 3  |     c     |  65     |
| 4  |     b     |  102    |
| 3  |     d     |  65     |
| 4  |     e     |  102    |
| .. |     ...   |  ...    |
```

and I am creating a report that says:

```
| categories         | Sum |
|     a              | 123 |
|    b;c             | 190 |
| many categories    | ... |
```

How can I, *using a formula*, loop and split through the values of a cell to calculate the sum?

Comment: Will you be typing the 1st column of the report? Or do you expect formulas to produce both columns?

Comment: i would be typing the categories i want in the report, lets say

col 1: a
and 
col2: bc
and
col3: a;c;e

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'loop' in Excel without using VBA; however 'looping' is not really what you need.

The SUMIFS formula has the arguments:

```
=SUMIFS(SUM_Range,CRITERIA1_Range,CRITERIA1,CRITERIA2_Range,CRITERIA2...)
```

In short, it adds all items in the SUM_Range, where the matching cells in the other ranges agree with their criteria.

ie:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,"a")
```

This will give you the total from column C, where column B for that row matches "a". Assume "a" is in cell D1, and all other terms are below. You can retype as follows, and drag down:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,D1)
```

Note that you have multiple terms in your search area - I advise you to split those into separate rows; it will make your life easier. Add them together after, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new column to your tables that define how categories are grouped:

```
| id | categorie |  number | group 
| 1  |     a     |  123    |   1
| 2  |     b     |  23     |   2
| 3  |     c     |  65     |   2
| 4  |     b     |  102    |   3
| 3  |     d     |  65     |   3
| 4  |     e     |  102    |   3
| .. |     ...   |  ...    |   4
```

and

```
| categories         | Sum | Group
|     a              | 123 |   1
|    b;c             | 190 |   2
| many categories    | ... |   3
```

Than use [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b):

> SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])

In your case, it will be:

```
SUMIF(GROUPCOLUMN, "=THATLINEGROUPCELL", NUMBERCOLUMN)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the formula solution.

Let's assume you type the categories you want summed in cell F2. For example you type in F2: `a;b`

Then in G2, enter this formula:

```
=SUM(C2:C7*IFERROR(B2:B7=MID(F2,COLUMN(OFFSET($A$1,,,,LEN(F2))),1),0))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You should adjust the references to `B2:B7` and `C2:C7` to match your source list.

You can use this formula for any arbitrary combination of single-letter category names to produce the sum of those categories.

Comment: Very interesting - I've never seen that use of COLUMN(OFFSET.... to create an array of numbered results like that.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to call your columns (ignoring ID) A and B and data rows start at 2 and go to row 7. And since I assume you want a table where you can just drag down the formula while referencing categories which are a, b, c... let's say those labels start at A10 (below):

in cell B10
`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,"<="&A10,$B$2:$B$7)`
then just drag this down with your labels (and obviously change the reference as needed)

For combinations just do a sumif()+sumif().

I was going to suggest a sumproduct array, but this is pretty easy.